Puppeteer: @puppeteer/browsers .install 404 (not working)
I'm working on a project that bundles a repo to an .exe using Node SEA. Bundling puppeteer causes me to need to install chrome myself, so I've switched from puppeteer to puppeteer-core + @puppeteer/browsers. Currently, I'm just trying to get a local chrome install to work, but I'm getting a 404:
Error in main function: Error: Got status code 404
   at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\core changes\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\httpUtil.js:135:31
   at ClientRequest.requestCallback (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\core changes\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\httpUtil.js:72:13)
   at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
   at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)

I think there's an issue with my installation options however, b/c the pptr dev documentation provides no context for valid values (https://pptr.dev/browsers-api/browsers.installoptions) and b/c I can't find an example online with string values assigned to these option variables (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10425), I'm not sure what specifically is causing the problem. Any help is appreciated!
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const puppeteerBrowsers = require('@puppeteer/browsers');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

const cacheDir = path.join(os.homedir(), '.CSVtoPDF', 'cache');
  
if(!fs.existsSync(cacheDir)){
  fs.mkdirSync(path.join(os.homedir(), '.CSVtoPDF'));
  fs.mkdirSync(cacheDir);
}

const installedBrowsers = await puppeteerBrowsers.getInstalledBrowsers({cacheDir});

if(installedBrowsers.length === 0){
  let browserInfo = await puppeteerBrowsers.install({
    browser: 'chrome',
    buildId: '1300313',
    cacheDir,
  });
}

// puppeteer-core stuff


Chrome versions: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

By locating the browser previously installed by puppeteer and console.log'ing its contents I was able to confirm that the buildId format was the issue.
eg
[
  InstalledBrowser {
    browser: 'chrome-headless-shell',
    buildId: '126.0.6478.126',
    platform: 'win64',
    executablePath: 'C:\\Users\\user\\.CSVtoPDFv1.07\\cache\\chrome-headless-shell\\win64-126.0.6478.126\\chrome-headless-shell-win64\\chrome-headless-shell.exe'
  }
]

the String needs to reflect is exact Chrome version number: eg '126.0.6478.126'. The other valid values for browser and platform are listed in the docs:
https://pptr.dev/browsers-api/browsers.browser
https://pptr.dev/browsers-api/browsers.browserplatform
